# C function to set global char*

Tags: c

I have some global var:

```
char *PROJECT_NAME;
char *DEVICE_NAME;
```

As I have many globals variables, what I want to do is to set value to these variable within a function.

What I'm doing is:

```
void main() {
 
  const char* fromArduinoJson = "VALUE";

  setVar(&PROJECT_NAME, fromArduinoJson);


  //this work
    //const char* device_name = doc["DEVICE_NAME"];
    //DEVICE_NAME = (char*) malloc(strlen(device_name)+1);
    //strcpy(DEVICE_NAME, (const char*)device_name);
  //---------


}

void setVar(char** var, const char* content) {
  *var = (char*) malloc(strlen(content)+1);
  strcpy(*var, (const char*)content);
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to write it the good way.

Comment: Do you want a solution in C or in C++? Using both tags is not normally recommended.

Comment: Use [strdup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup).

Comment: Do you have a declaration of `setVar` before you use it?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - is not a well issue description.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, I have, in a .h file with also extern on my globals.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I do DEVICE_NAME = strdup( doc["DEVIVE_NAME"]);, but the program break on it.

Comment: This works for me with the ```setVar``` function declared at the top as well as  ```#include <string.h> #include <stdlib.h>```

Comment: I do not know what `doc` is, but I think your issue comes from the typo on `DEVIVE_NAME` (It should be `DEVICE_NAME`)... And by the way, do not forget to free the memory at the end of your program.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I know I've to free them but I m on a ESP8266, so my global var are allways available until I reboot.

Comment: @Ripytide thanks to confirm it.

Comment: @JérômeRichard that was a typo !

Comment: To everyone, thank you !

Comment: Just a comment on this: I would avoid dynamic memory allocation (malloc) in embedded programs if at all possible. So I would pick a maximum size for your globals and declare them as character arrays of that size, then copy into them. If the copy is bigger than maximum, create a loud noisy error failure. With this you never end up with failures from running out of memory later in the program because someone used a gigantic PROJECT_NAME at the beginning.

Comment: Suggesting a good solution requires a bit more information. I assume this is an embedded application. When is the value of these strings known? Do they really need to be modifiable? It seems strange that you would need to copy the strings instead of just initializing them to point at the right value. E.g. `const char *PROJECT_NAME="VALUE";`.

Comment: It's an ESP8266 with 80kb of RAM. It has WiFi. It's possible to put a file system on it (littleFS). It cans run a little http server, MQTT, post requests, etc... So for example the SSID and the WiFi password should be modifiable, like an API KEY and other stuffs. So my config is store in a JSON string in a file. I read this file on the setup to initialise my globals. Sure I can make Globals with maximum size and check the user value size/length to validate.